# SAS macro for date in dhms format

Tags: sas

I have two resolved macro variables:

```
&beg is “01MAY2017”
&end is “31OCT2017”
```

I want to create new macro which will have date format `dhms`

I tried the below queries but I am getting Jan 1960 as the value:

```
%let start =%sysfunc(putn(&beg, datetime20.));
%let start1=%sysfunc(putn(&end, datetime20.));
```

Below are the values I am getting:

```
01JAN1960:05:49:00
01JAN1960:05:53:03
```

I want the result as `01MAY2017:00:00:00` and `31OCT2017:00:00:00`

Comment: You would get an error from the PUTN() function with the values you show for your macro variables since it expects a number and not a character string.

Answer (score 2):

The datetime format is expecting you to provide the number of *seconds* since 1st January 1960, but you've given it a date literal that resolves to the number of *days* instead. Try using `dhms` to convert to datetime before applying the format:

```
%let BEG = '01MAY2017'd;
%let START = %sysfunc(dhms(&BEG,0,0,0),datetime20.);
%put START = &START;
```

Answer (score 1):

@user667489 has a good and flexible solution.

If you need to add `:00:00:00` systematically, another way would simply be:

```
%let start = %sysfunc(putn(&beg, date9.)):00:00:00;
```

Answer (score 0):

Macro variables just contain text.  How you use them determines their meaning.  Also SAS stores dates as number of days and datetime as number of seconds.

Now if your macro variable just contains a string that looks like a date in DATE format then you can just append a constant text that looks like a time in TIME format to create a string that looks like a datetime value in DATETIME format.

```
%let beg=01MAY2017 ;
%let start=&beg.:00:00:00 ;
```

If you actually have a date value in your macro variable, then you can use SAS functions to convert it to a datetime value.

For example if your macro variable had a date literal you could use the DHMS() function to generate a datetime literal.

```
%let beg='01MAY2017'd ;
%let start="%sysfunc(dhms(&beg,0,0,0),datetime20)"dt ;
```

If your macro variable just had a raw unformatted date value (ie the number of days) then you could convert it to the number of seconds.

```
%let beg=20940;
%let start=%sysfunc(dhms(&beg,0,0,0));
```

And you will end up with START=1809216000.